# Why the LimeSurvey new user creation email does not reach the new user?

Tags: limesurvey

When I create a new user in LimeSurvey and send them the automatic email with the credentials, the users do not receive the email, and not even in the junk folder.

Do you know what could be the problem here? Could be the firewall from the company?

Thank you very much for your answers.

Jorge

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have to fix your smtp server first. LimeSurvey use mail by default, but you can choose other method.

See : http://manual.limesurvey.org/Global_settings#Email_settings

Comment: dear Denis-- thx for the answer. Great to hear from you- i love to hear from you what happened. and how to fix issues. One Question though.  do we need the mails - or can we send a simple surrey without any mail-settngs touched!?  Love to hear from you